# Prepare PHP code for DateTime

Tags: php, date, exception

So, I have an `SQL` query result loaded into an `array`. Now, I want to display it in a `html` table. This the code I used to use.

```
$table = "<table><thead><tr><th>".implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($res)))."</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); ++$i) {
  $table .= "<tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($res[$i]); ++$j) {
      $table .= "<td>".$res[$i][$j]."</td>"; //here is the issue if it's date
    }
  $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody></table>";
echo $table;
```

If a certain value is `Date` or `DateTime` then I get the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`.

Here is my next step which is causing the exact same error. I don't really understand why.

```
$table = "<table><thead><tr><th>".implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($res)))."</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($res); ++$i) {
      $table .= "<tr>";
        for($j = 0; $j < count($res[$i]); ++$j) {
          try {
            $table .= "<td>".$res[$i][$j]."</td>"; //the issue is here again, so try doesn't seem to work as expected
          }
          catch (Exception $e){
            $table .= "<td>".$res[$i][$j]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</td>";
          }
        }
      $table .= "</tr>";
    }
    $table .= "</tbody></table>";
    echo $table;
```

So, let's say I want to write a general function for any query result in which I can't tell in advance what record has what type. How can I prepare the code to handle dates?

Comment: You could use `if ($res[$i][$j] instanceof DateTime)` to check if you got a date and then handle it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether its a date time object using is_a function and handle it

```
if (is_a($res[$i][$j], 'DateTime')) {
// handle code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own error handler to catch the exception as you want to.

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if ( E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR===$errno ) {
        echo "'catched' catchable fatal error\n";
        throw new Exception();
  }
  return false;
}
set_error_handler('errorHandler');


$t = new DateTime();
try{
    $table = "<td>".$t."</td>";
}catch(Exception $e){
    $table = "<td>".$t->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."</td>";
}

echo $table;
```

This way an exception is thrown that you can catch. It would output

```
'catched' catchable fatal error
<td>2016-07-14 12:57:27</td>%
```